# Comparing a range of numbers to be in a range defined by two cell values

Tags: excel

Suppose the excel sheet contains MAX values in Column A and MIN values in Column B. I have to figure out if the range defined by cell values in each row contains one of the values in "100 ± 10", and get the results as TRUE or FALSE in Column C.

That is if A1 = 120, B1 = 80 then C1 should be TRUE. Because one of the value in "100 ± 10" falls between the range 80-120.

And, if A2 = 89, B1 = 70 then C2 should be FALSE.

But, if A3 = 91, B1 = 70 then C3 should be TRUE.

Is it possible using only formulas in excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
=IF(OR(AND(B1>=90,B1<=110),AND(90>=B1,90<=A1)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

[image]

***NOTE :*** For formula to work, `Column A` values should be greater than corresponding `Column B` values.

Comment: Works like a charm. It would be great, if you add some explanation to it for future references.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to check whether a value is between 2 numbers:

```
=AND(val>MIN(num1,num2),val<MAX(num1,num2))
```

Source: https://exceljet.net/formula/value-is-between-two-numbers

Comment: Well, I definitely agree with what you say. But, the point is to check a range of values to be in another range. Your solution only checks a single value in a range.

Answer (score 0):

To check if any of values from your range falls inside of your set values, please use this formula `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--($F$2:$F$5<A2),--($F$2:$F$5>B2))>0,"True","False")`. Instead of `$F$2:$F$5` put your range of values.